# Can't fly the Profit Bird 700m in one run!

Tags: jetpack-joyride

How do I fly the Profit Bird 700m in one run? It's driving me mad as I'm stuck on my last mission and can't complete. I've tried Missile Jammer and DeZappinator to decrease the risk of getting caught but 700m on profit bird seems impossible.Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way and most efficient way to easily get it is to have Dezappinator and Instant Ride.

Here's a cool trick with Instant Ride. If you spawn with a Teleporter, and decide to retry the mission in the pause menu, you'll guarantee a Teleporter when you try again. You can retry as many times as you want, and as long as you don't die and get to the rewards screen, you will always get the Teleporter as the starting vehicle.  This works with any other vehicle (Stomper, Gravity Guy, Dragon, Motorcycle, etc.). The only time this won't work is if you get a 750m boost or 1500 meter boost.

So if you're getting frustrated with the Profit Bird and RNG, use the Instant Ride until you get the Profit Bird, and keep trying. If you fail you can easily hit pause to retry the mission. And the first 700m are usually the easiest, allowing you to get the mission easily enough.  It may be frustrating, but the more you practice out with the Profit Bird the easier it will be to complete the 700m challenges.

Remember that this tip works for the other missions like "Run 700m with Gravity Guy in 1 run", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first answer. Also, when using any vehicle, try keeping your fingers at the lower half of the screen. And also try using  free ride and dezapinator. One time, I flew from the 1st sector to the 5th sector on the profit bird using both of these gadgets. Oh and one more tip, also try keeping your profit bird on the floor until a zapper or missile comes on the floor. That way you have a better chance of surviving because it is hard to stay at the top then drop down to the bottom with the profit bird. Keeping your bird on the floor will increase your chances of going farther. Good luck!